# Merge 5 tables data into Master Table

Tags: t-sql, inner-join, outer-join, join

```
Main Table : MT
===============
PK, C1, C2
==========
1, X, X
2, X, X
3, X, X
..........
100, X, X


Table 1 :T1
===============
PK, TC1
=======
2, D1
3, D1

Table 2: T2
===============
PK, TC2
=======
3, D2

Table 3: T3
===============
PK, TC3
=======
4, D3

Table 4: T4
===============
PK, TC4
=======
2, D4
```

I want output of Master Table after making some join or any how as below :

```
Master Table
===============
PK,C1,C2,TC1,TC2,TC3,TC4
========================
(1,X,X,null,null,null,null)
(2,X,X,D1,null,null,D4)
(3,X,X,D1,D2,null,null)
(4,X,X,null,null,D3,null)
```

I tried

```
select * from
MT inner join T1 on MT.PK=T1.PK
inner join T2 on MT.PK = T2.PK
inner join T2 on MT.PK = T3.PK
inner join T2 on MT.PK = T4.PK
```

But I am getting some rows duplicate. Even tried distinct still getting duplicate. I think there must be some other alternative to achieve this thing.

Comment: I don't think the query you have in your question is the one you executed - as three of the joins are hitting the same T2 table - and nothing aliases T3 or T4 - so the query should have errored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your existing query is you are using an `INNER JOIN` between all of the tables. An INNER JOIN requires that the value of the column being joined on exists in both tables.

It seems to me that you want to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
select MT.PK, MT.C1, MT.C2, T1.TC1, T2.TC2, T3.TC3, T4.TC4
from MT 
left join T1 on MT.PK=T1.PK
left join T2 on MT.PK = T2.PK
left join T3 on MT.PK = T3.PK
left join T4 on MT.PK = T4.PK;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c40fe/4)

A LEFT JOIN will return all rows from the `MT` table and then the data from the other tables if it exists when the `PK` matches.

Comment: Sorry. I tried. But still getting duplicate rows. Multiple rows containing MT.PK values. I want each row of MT and with corresponding other tables values.

Comment: @sapatelbaps If your PK exists multiple times in the joined tables, then which one do you want to return?

Comment: The example u shared on sqlfiddle is correct and I resolved the issue. @bluefeet